# TYPO3 internal links inserted from the ckeditor are not "converted"

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typolink

TYPO3 internal links inserted from the backend are not "converted", they stay in the same format, for example an internal link will appear like this in the frontend: `<a href="t3://page?uid=2">internal link test</a>`
I'm a beginner using TYPO3 8.7.8, and a custom ckeditor configuration. I have also extended the ckeditor with my own plugin. How can I find what is causing this?

Edit 1:
Seems like none of the links prefixed with `"t3://"` are working. Is it possibble that the LinkService is not called?

Comment: Thanks a lot, same here. Because of https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/frontend_editing/issues/287

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After uninstalling every non-vital extension and clearing every possible cache and a few hours of debugging we have found the problem: the "frontend_editing" extension - only if the user is logged in into the backend!

Comment: For me the solution was to find in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306258/how-to-get-rendered-links-of-a-html-element-in-typo3-7-6 and had to do with using f.fomat.html instead of f.format.raw in custom content elements output of fields with rte.

Comment: Using `TYPO3 9.5.7`and the latest `frontend editing` and have the same problems. Frontend editing is very buggy at the moment (1.5.0) .. hands off! Uninstall the extension and all ckeditor-links are correct.

Comment: @user2310852 Use the following code in your template and it will work with ext:frontend_editing: `<core:contentEditable table="tt_content" field="bodytext" uid="{data.uid}">
    <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">{data.bodytext}</f:format.html>
</core:contentEditable>`. The important part is the `parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc"` in the html viewhelper.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the answer of @t_csba before, I had the same issue with installed `ext:frontend_editing` but not active frontend editing for the user. The solution for this issue is the following code:

```
<core:contentEditable table="tt_content" field="bodytext" uid="{data.uid}">
    <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">{data.bodytext}</f:format.html>
</core:contentEditable>
```

The important part in the html viewhelper is `parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc"`.