# powermail: rendered links in HTML element in typo3 9

Tags: typo3, typoscript, powermail

Default behaviour of Typo3 is that Typo3-Links are not rendered in a HTML-element. There is a workaround, see here: [How to get rendered links of a HTML element in TYPO3 7.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306258/how-to-get-rendered-links-of-a-html-element-in-typo3-7-6)

Unfortunately, in Typo3 9.5.7 this seems not to work. As described above, I replaced html.html by this:

```
<f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
    <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">
        {data.bodytext}
    </f:format.html>
</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
```

I also replaced html.html by this, did't work for me:

```
<f:format.html>{data.bodytext}</f:format.html>
```

In the HTML-element I tested these variations of links, but none works:

```
<a class="download-link" href="t3://file?uid=107" target="_blank">Download (PDF)</a>
<link t3resources/cms/pdf/linux.pdf>Administration von Linux-PCs</link>
<link 27>Linktext</link>
```

Comment: UPDATE: the reason why I am having this problem, and why the above solution doesn't work, is that I am using a HTML-element in a powermail formular. Enabling rendering of typo3 links in HTML-elements does work as described above, but not in powermail formulars...

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried setting plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.htmlForHtmlFields = 1 in the constants?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29793732)